# Gitlab migration from older version to new version

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I am trying to migrate the entire repository from server A to Server B.
The current gitlab in server A is running in Version:7.7.2 , and Server B is running in Version:12.2.4

What is the best way to migrate the entire repositories from server A (Version:7.7.2) to server B (Version:12.2.4).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to update your remote on your local workstation and push the code to the new GitLab server. Here are the steps:

1. Clone the project to your local workstation if it isn't already: `git clone --mirror git@gitlab.example.com:group/project.git`
2. Create the new project in the new GitLab server.
3. Copy the clone URL from the new project in the new GitLab server.
4. Add a new remote to your checked out repository: `cd project` (from earlier clone). Then, `git remote add new-gitlab <clone_url_from_new_server>`
5. Push to the new server: `git push new-gitlab --mirror`

There's a decent post about how to 'mirror' a project at http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/

Comment: I guess we should mention that you'll loose all the additional data stored in the old gitlab (if any). These include: issues, CI history and configuration, merge/pull requests, members configuration.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. If you want to retain all of this then a backup/restore, project import/export, or an in-place upgrade are all options.

Answer (score 0):

First Create backup in your Server A, along with the config and secrets.

Then install the same gitlab server in Server B, copy the backup from Server A to Server B, restore backup and place the config and secrets where the exact location it is suppose to be from Server A.

Then test the Gitlab in Server B if all is working well.

Then curl download the list of new version of gitlab in server B

Run

```
apt update gitlab-ee or gitlab-ce -y
```

Done.